# Android wait picasso to be completed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get an image then going to new activity

```
 Picasso.get().load(imgURL).into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {

                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    imgbase64_str= Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, 0);

                    if(imgbase64_str==null)
                    {
                    Log.d("if null","is null");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    Log.d("if null","not null");
                    }
                }
            });

            Intent intent = new Intent(login.this,register.class);
            intent.putExtra("imgbase64_str",imgbase64_str);

            startActivity(intent);
```

but when I go to the new activity I will find that `imgbase64_str` is null, but `Log.d` not null
 so I should wait for it

Answer (score 0):

Please modify the logging section as follows.

```
if(imgbase64_str!=null && !imgbase64_str.equals(""))
   {
    Log.d("if null","not null");
   }
    else
   {
    Log.d("if null","is null");
   }
```

Comment: returning `not null` but still also writing it late